# How can I configure a Django website to work with Apache VirtualHosts?

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, virtualhost

I recently started developing Django websites and I want to deploy them on a CentOS VPS with mod_wsgi and Apache.

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7) and it works perfectly, but I would like to have more than one Django website running at the same time, so I tried to create multiple virtual hosts inside a proper config file, and there comes the problem.

```
<VirtualHost the.ip.of.server:80>
    ErrorLog /root/praxis.error.log

    Alias /static /root/Praxis/static
    <Directory /root/Praxis/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /root/Praxis/Praxis>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess Praxis python-path=/root/Praxis:/root/Env/Praxis/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup Praxis
    WSGIScriptAlias /praxis /root/Praxis/Praxis/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

**If I delete the VirtualHost opening and closing tag the site will work as expected, but if I keep those tags I will constantly receive a 404 error.**

I really don't understand why everything works fine only without tags.

I also tried to switch between IP-based virtual hosting and name-based virtual hosting but nothing changed.

Here follows also wsgi.py

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

sys.path.append('/root/Praxis/Praxis')

os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/root/Praxis/.python-egg'
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Praxis.settings'

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

In my **httpd.conf** file I also have:

```
Listen 80

ServerName ip.to.the.server #without port specified
```

and

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80 <-- THIS IS A COMMENT RIGHT NOW
```

Thank you all in advance for the effort, I hope someone will be able to help me, I'm struggling with this so hard! Thank you guys.

---

**PROBLEM SOLVED!** I figured out that (I dunno why, actually) all VIrtualHosts had to be placed into httpd.conf file and not into external .conf files. So I placed'em all there and removed all the "IncludeOptional" directives. That's it!

Comment: Please remove `Solved` from your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

virtualhost.conf :

```
<VirtualHost you.ip.address:80>

  ServerAdmin admin@you.ip.address
  ServerName you.ip.address
  ServerAlias you.ip.address

  <Directory /You/directory/where/wsgifile>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>  
  WSGIScriptAlias / /You/directory/where/wsgifile/wsgi.py

  <Directory /You/directory/where/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory> 
  Alias /media /You/directory/where/media

  <Directory /You/directory/where/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory> 
  Alias /static /You/directory/where/static

</VirtualHost>
```

in You httpd.conf:

ServerName your.server.name for example www.example.com or your ip

Your wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/Path/to/You/DjanoSite')
sys.path.append(r'/Path/to/You/DjanoSite/DjangoSite/Wherewsgifile')
sys.path.append(r'/Path/to/You/media')
sys.path.append(r'/Path/to/You/static')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DjangoSite.settings'
import django
django.setup()
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I still have 404 error when I try to reach that page.

Comment: Where located You DjangoSite folder

Comment: You DjangoSite folder located in /root ?

Comment: Yes! I know is not good to deploy stuff as root user, when everything will work I will switch everything under a non-root user

Comment: Try answer#1 and answer#2. You will can not to run apache with 80 port as non root user. Exists many methods, such us create django-project in /var/www directory or in /home directory with root privelegies.